# Awk regex: how to remove all punctuation except when in the middle of a word?

Tags: bash, regex, awk, text-editing

Following information gathered on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677997/how-to-remove-punctuation-marks-using-awk), I wanted to use this code to fill my needs, however the code provided wasn't working for more than one punctuation character (e.g. '...'). I thus wanted to adapt it, so here is my bit of code:

`awk '{gsub(/^[[:punct:]]+|[[:punct:]]+$/, "")} 1' myfile.txt`

However this is not working as expected. Can someone explain why, as I'm learning bash and awk?

Input file:

@Username you are a nice person, I like you!
I hate @username, she's not one I'd like to have dinner with...
he told me '@Username is such a horrible man', but I didn't listen...

Expected result:

Username you are a nice person I like you
I hate username she's not one I'd like to have dinner with
he told me Username is such a horrible man but I didn't listen

Thanks a lot for any pointer, I've spent quite a bit of time trying many things, but I just don't get it.

Comment: If `sed` is fine, try: `sed -E 's/(([[:space:]]|^)[[:punct:]]+|[[:punct:]]+([[:space:]]|$))/\2\3/g' myfile.txt`. This matches not only punctuation at start and end of lines but also at start and end of any spaces/words. `awk` however doesn't support back-references reliably to preserve the spaces. It doesn't support `word. .word` since one space is matched only one time, so for this you'd need to add another case in the sed regex, if it can appear in your file

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It works as expected indeed, thanks a lot! It's a bit of a pity that `awk` is not the ideal solution for the job, but for the time being, `sed` will do! : )

I'm using it to clean tweet files, so actually, many types of situations can appear, this is why it's difficult to find a perfect program that would delete everything except apostrophes that are in the middle of relevant strings. This program works for most cases however, so thanks a lot! : )